# Permission Denied on mkdir php with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, mariadb, rhel

I am struggling with an issue on LEMP stack. I cannot make my nginx user to create directory via php script.

My stack is 
RHEL 7.2
NGINX
MariadB
PHP

I installed the stack successfully and used following code for creating directory in index.php

```
        <?php
           echo(exec("whoami"));
           mkdir("test",0777,true);
           $error=error_get_last();
           echo $error['mssage'];
        ?>
```

Output 
               nginx
               mkdir(): Permission denied

Nginx excecutes `PHP` via `nginx` user.

```
Applied 'chown -R nginx: nginx <working folder>'
Applied 'chmod -R 0777 <working folder>
```

But above script gives same permission denied error.

My plan is to install Wordpress and import sites to this web server. But since permission is denied on working folder of nginx , Wordpress is not able to create new directories or move content from one folder to other.

Comment: So one reason might be that SELinux is not allowing Nginx to write to a directory, although this is unlikely. To check this **temporarily**, execute `sudo su` so that you're a root user and then run `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`. Try running the script again. If it still gives the same error, then enable SELinux again `echo 1 > /selinux/enforce` and post the permissions of the directory structure that you're trying to write to.

Answer (score 2):

check your nginx.conf file from /etc/nginx

and get the nginx username using

```
 sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

For example if the username is www-data then use

```
sudo chown -R www-data /home/www/ || /foldername/
```

then go to your file directory

```
cd /home/www/
```

check the permissions in shell using

```
ls -l
```

Now check the `mkdir()` in your development

Answer (score 1):

Set SELINUX to disabled or permissive in /etc/selinux/config

If SELINUX has to be Enforcing, use semanage to change the context of the MySQL datadir and its contents.

shell> sestatus

```
SELinux status: enabled
SELinuxfs mount: /selinux
Current mode: enforcing
Mode from config file: enforcing
Policy version: 24
Policy from config file: targeted
```

then you have SELinux on.

Other possible tips:

```
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,591661 (mysqld service won't start after server move)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,568810 (MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,275498 (Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.197' (13))
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,252406 (PHP Remote connection Issue)
```